# Android Java onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, oncreate

So I followed Google's first Android app sample.  If I tapped the send button, it opened up the `DisplayMessageActivity`. But upon tapped the back button (left arrow) from the DisplayMessageActivity, the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the `MainActivity` got called again. It looks like it created a new instance of `MainActivity`.  I could verify this by setting a bool value in `onCreate` of `MainActivity` and it was not retained.

How do you go back to the previous instance of `MainActivity` (the caller)?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Androids Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

If you want to access the state of the activity again, I would suggest to use the method

> public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)

to save the current state.

Retrieve the previously saved values in this method:

> public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

An example can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#oncreate)

Comment: The onSaveInstanceState never got called.  So this if (savedInstanceState != null)  in the onCreate did not occur.

Comment: hmm, the method `onSaveInstanceState` should be called when the Activity gets destroyed.   
As you said, if the method `onSaveInstanceState` never gets called, the param in the `onCreate` will be `null`.   
Are you sure the OnSaveInstanceState is correctly written (in the MainActivity) with the `@Override` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can call finish() in the onClickListener of the back arrow view. It will finish the DisplayMessageActivity and you will return to the caller activity (MainActivity in your case).

Something like:

```
backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       finish();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like it created a new instance of MainActivity.

Yes, I think, that was quite a normal behavior.

Basically, Android OS would keep only one Activity at once so that free as many memory resources as possible.

You should design your application with [understanding about such lifecycle concepts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

You can save some of the states of your Activity in certain manners (`Parcelable`, `Bundle` or `SharedPreferences`, etc.).